# create image with transparent background with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I am currently working on a script to process assets for a game. I am breaking down old assets and reorganizing them for a new format. The original images have transparent backgrounds already. When I append images back together there is a white background applied to part of the image.

Most sources say to just use `-background "#FFFFFF"` to turn anything white transparent. But some of my assets use white and if I use this then the asset is destroyed.

This is the [First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK81U.png) I am merging with this [Second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6uDq.png) and here is the [output of script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5THpI.png)

here is part of my script. I would like to just say `-background none` but that does not work. How can I create an image without adding a background?

```
convert output3.png output4.png -append output6.png
convert output6.png output5.png -append output7.png
convert output7.png space.png -append -background none output8.png
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, I don't experience what you say. Please notice that the parameter is `none`, you typed `nune`. I downloaded your first and second pics and got a good output using `convert first.png second.png -append -background none output.png`

Comment: Damnit. Haha. Well fixed that typo but now I am getting the same problem but it has a black background instead of white...